# AWS S3: Remove Object Prefix From Thousands of Files in Complex Directory Structure

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I am using AWS CLI interface to manage files/objects in S3.  I have thousands of objects buried in a complex system of nested folders (subfolders), I want to elevate all of the objects to the “root” of the S3 bucket, in one folder at the root of the bucket `(s3://bucket/folder/file.txt)`.

I've tried using this command:

```
 aws s3 s3://bucket-a/folder-a s3://bucket-a --recursive --exclude “*” --include “*.txt”
```

When I use the mv command, it carries over the prefixes (directory paths) of each object resulting in the same nested folder system.  Here is what I want to accomplish:

Desired Result:
Where:

```
s3://bucket-a/folder-a/file-1.txt
s3://bucket-a/folder-b/folder-b1/file-2.txt
s3://bucket-a/folder-c/folder-c1/folder-c2/ file-3.txt
```

Output:
s3://bucket-a/file-1.txt
s3://bucket-a/file-2.txt
s3://bucket-a/file-3.txt

I have been told, that I need to use a bash script to accomplish my desired result.  Here is a sample script that was provided to me:

```
#!/bin/bash
#BASH Script to move objects without directory structure
bucketname='my-bucket'
for key in $(aws s3api list-objects --bucket "${my-bucket}" --query "Contents[].{Object:Key}" --output text) ;
  do
    echo "$key"
    FILENAME=$($key | awk '{print $NF}' FS=/)
    aws s3 cp s3://$my-bucket/$key s3://$my-bucket/my-folder/$FILENAME
  done
```

When I run this bash script, I get an error:

> A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

I tested the connection with another aws s3 command and confirmed that it works.  I added policies to the user to include all privledges to s3, I have no idea what I am doing wrong here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you, by chance, passing your AWS credentials in environmental variables and using sudo to run the script?  (And just to be nit-picky, S3 is actually a totally flat filesystem, with no real folders/directories.  An object named "foo/bar" is just that, an object named "foo/bar", not an object named "bar" in a folder called "foo" http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html)

Comment: You may have enabled list permissions on the bucket but not on some of the underlying paths. Are you able to list all files recursively in the bucket? Also, your script is going to issue an extremely large number of copy commands, and doesn't handle duplicate filenames (you may overwrite data)

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but I don't understand the `$` at the end of a couple of lines here.  What is `--que$` supposed to do?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot sorry about that, I corrected the statement.

Comment: Actually, I should have realize the error occurs before that line anyway.  Scrap the script for a minute and just run the exact same `aws s3api list-objects ...` command directly.  That seems to be what isn't working and the rest of this is a distraction from the root cause.

Comment: When I use this command:

    aws s3api list-objects --bucket s3://my-bucket --query 'Contents[].{Key: Key, Size: Size}'

I get this error: "Unknown output type: None:

Comment: So, I got a little bit of success by replacing 
    "${my-bucket}"
with just 
    my-bucket
but now I am recieving this error message:
> folder-b/folder-b1/folder-b/folder-b1/file-2.txt
> ./tmp.sh: line 7: folder-b/folder-b1/folder-b/folder-b1/file-2.txt: No such file or directory
> A client error (404) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "folder-b/folder-b1/folder-b/folder-b1/file-2.txt" does not exist
> Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining

Answer (score 0):

That script looks messed up, no means on setting a variable called bucketname and trying to use another one called my-bucket, what happens if you try this ?

```
#!/bin/bash
#BASH Script to move objects without directory structure
bucketname='my-bucket'
for key in $(aws s3api list-objects --bucket "${bucketname}" --query "Contents[].{Object:Key}" --output text) ;
  do
    echo "$key"
    FILENAME=$($key | awk '{print $NF}' FS=/)
    aws s3 cp s3://$bucketname/$key s3://$bucketname/my-folder/$FILENAME
  done
```